# Ajax send JSON and fetch data using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have jquery code output json data and I need to send this data to to url and fetch using php

**Code:**

```
JSON.stringify(showtimes)
```

**Output:**

```
[{"show_id":"1","movie_id":"20","cinema_id":"10","status":"0","times":"00:00"},{"show_id":"2","movie_id":"21","cinema_id":"11","status":"1","times":"01:00"}, ... etc]
```

I need to send this json data `JSON.stringify(showtimes)` via ajax to url and fetch json using php.

**My ajax code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/save/',
    data: JSON.stringify(showtimes),  
    success: function(data){}
});
```

**Question:**

- Check ajax code is true ?
- How fetch data using PHP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should assign a data key to your json object in the javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/save/',
    data: {json : JSON.stringify(showtimes)},  
    success: function(data){}
});
```

Within your PHP would would access the JSON string as:

```
$_POST['json'];
```

Secondly, within PHP you will want to gather your data using the following example:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
```

You can then access your JSON array as an associative array:

```
foreach($json as $show_details){
    $show_id = $show_details['show_id'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the ajax response valid JSON by using something like below:

```
function isValidJSON($request_data)
{
  return (json_decode($request_data) != NULL) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

You can then use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the data.

Answer (score 0):

To decode json to php array use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

  //It is ajax

}
```